# How do I pass a series of patterns into awk from a shell script?

Tags: awk, solaris, ksh

I've got a series of patterns stored in `foo.txt` and I want to iterate over those patterns and see which match lines in file `bar.txt`.

```
while read PWW
do
   cat user/dump/bar.txt | awk '/${PWW}/{print $2}' >> user/dump/out.txt
done < user/dump/foo.txt
```

`foo.txt`:

```
2100001b32
2100001b38
3100001b35
4100001b28
5100001b46
6100001b56
```

`bar.txt`:

```
2100001b32 good
2100001b38 bad
3100001b35 okay
4100001b28 large
5100001b46 good
6100001b56 bad
```

desired `out.txt`:

```
good
bad
okay
large
good
bad
```

I am unable to search for the values in `foo.txt`. The while loop runs and gives me empty output. I guess `awk` is looking for `${PWW}` (literally) instead of its values from `foo.txt`.

How can I make it work?
My environment is Solaris 5.10, using Korn shell, with basic `awk`
(old `awk`).

Comment: Don't use your approach! (Remove useless `cat`s, avoid loops in shells if possible, don't repeatedly call (`awk`-) processes in loops unnecessarily.) - Instead use an `awk`-only approach, like the suggested "pure `awk`" answer below. - `awk` can accept a file list (as many other commands also do), it does implicit (fast) looping, and the resulting code is much simpler.

Comment: @Janis my question is just an example. In reality what i wanted can only be achieved with loop. if its just a single file operation i could have done a straight-forward AWK. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: `awk` accepts lists of files as arguments, not only "single file". - As said; the way you wrote your sample (with all its deficiencies) is a strong indication that you may not know what's possible or sensible. - It would be helpful if you just tell us exactly "what you wanted"; we could certainly make good suggestions. - Anyway; your choice.

Comment: The problem as stated could probably be done with a `grep -f foo.txt`.  If there are additional constraints, edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your quotes. In unix shells including bash: single quotes pass text unmodified to the program (so as you said passes `${PWW}`, double quotes allow expansion of variables.

In your example you want `${PWW}` to be expanded but not `$2`, you can do this like this:

```
awk "/${PWW}/"'{print $2}'
awk /${PWW}/{print '$2'}
awk "/${PWW}/{print \$2}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i did not know the difference between double quote and single quote. Now i will remember. Its working now.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a pure-awk solution:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print a[$1]}' bar.txt foo.txt
good
bad
okay
large
good
bad
```

#### How it works

The script reads in bar.txt first and saves its information in array `a`.  It then reads foo.txt and prints out the corresponding value.

- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next}`

  FNR is the number of lines read from the current file and NR is the number of lines read so far total.  Thus, if `FNR==NR`, we are still reading the first file (bar.txt).  If so, `a[$1]=$2` is used to add an entry to array `a` saving these values.  Then, we skip the rest of the commands in the script and start over on the `next` line.
- `print a[$1]`

  If we get here, we are reading the second file, foo.txt.  We read foo.txt line by line.  For each line, we look up the value corresponding to the key in the first column and print it.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical method of passing string values from the shell into `awk` is through the `-v var=val` option.

If you want to use those strings for a pattern match, traditionally with `/.../`,  you need write an explicit match against the entire line:

```
awk -v pattern=${PWW} '$0 ~ pattern {print $2}'
```

BTW, for Solaris 10, `nawk` is recommended over plain old `awk`, if only for better error messages than `"bailing out at ..."`